# How to calculate SAVI with MODIS in Google Earth Engine (Getting Error: Image.select: Pattern 'B2' did not match any bands.)

Tags: gis, google-earth-engine, satellite-image

I am trying to calculate **SAVI** vegetation index using MODIS data. But I am getting an **error** showing:

> Image.select: Pattern 'B2' did not match any bands.

**Code:**

```
countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
canada = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq("country_na", "Canada"))
image = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD09A1")\
            .filterDate('2017-01-01','2017-12-31')\
            .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10))\
            .filterBounds(canada)\
            .median()\
            .clip(canada)

savi = image.expression(
    '1.5*((NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED+0.5))',{
        'NIR':image.select('B2'),
        'RED':image.select('B1')
    }).rename('savi')

saviVis = {'min':0.0, 'max':1, 'palette':['yellow', 'green']}
Map = geemap.Map()
Map.addLayer(savi, saviVis, 'SAVI')
Map
```

Why am I getting this error? Isn't **B1** designated to **Red** and **B2** to **NIR**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general thing to do when you hit this type of problem is to start examining the dataset for what is actually there — how many images are you matching, what properties and bands those images have, etc. I found two problems:

1. Your filter criteria matched zero images. Therefore the collection is empty, and therefore the `median()` image from that collection has no bands at all. (You can check this by putting the collection in a variable and printing the `size()` of it.) You will need to adjust the criteria.

   It seems that the main reason they didn't match is that the images in `MODIS/061/MOD09A1` do not have a `CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE` property.
2. The band names for `MODIS/061/MOD09A1` are not `B1`, `B2`, ... but `sur_refl_b01`, `sur_refl_b02` and so on. You can see this with the Inspector in the Earth Engine Code Editor, or on [the dataset description page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MOD09A1#bands).

Perhaps you were working from information about a different dataset?

With the two problems above fixed, your code produces some results. This is the (JS) version I produced while testing ([Code Editor link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/540401df0862a884e54bcd09dd691c69)):

```js
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var canada = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq("country_na", "Canada"));
var images = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD09A1")
            .filterDate('2017-01-01','2017-12-31')
            // .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10))
            .filterBounds(canada);
// print(images);
var image = images.median().clip(canada);

Map.addLayer(canada);
Map.addLayer(image);

var savi = image.expression(
    '1.5*((NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED+0.5))',{
        'NIR':image.select('sur_refl_b02'),
        'RED':image.select('sur_refl_b01')
    }).rename('savi');

var saviVis = {'min':0.0, 'max':1, 'palette':['yellow', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(savi, saviVis, 'SAVI')
```

Comment: I was working with Sentinel dataset then I shifted to MODIS for some reason. I did not have any idea that MODIS does not have CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE property. This was causing issues and yes the band names too. I have fixed these two and now it's working fine. How do we specify the Cloud percentage in MODIS then?

Comment: @user14 Every individual data set has its own provided properties. Cloudiness isn't an inherently known fact — it's something the data provider chooses to provide an _estimate_ of, or not. If there isn't such data then you have to build something to compute it yourself. Detecting clouds can be a quite hard problem — there is no simple solution that works everywhere.